# Add delay at boot

Tags: boot

I'd like to **add a 2 minute delay** to the boot time of my **Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server**.

To do this on a Raspberry Pi I simply edited the  `config.txt`  in  `/boot`  to include `boot_delay=120` .

**Which file** should I edit on Ubuntu to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any issue you are trying to fix by adding delay? If yes then you might want to describe it as there might be other more suitable fixes. Otherwise if @bulletbob answer works for you, you can help others with similar issue to find the right solution by [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT=n` to what ever you want in seconds. Once you're done, you need to run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help!